¿Cómo vincular correctamente cuadros combinados anidados que se encuentran en dos formularios distintos de access?
Tengo 4 cuadros combinados anidados o sincronizados, que al elegir determinada opción en el primero, en el segundo, en el tercero y cuarto van apareciendo en cascada las diferentes listas de opciones correspondientes en los subsiguientes según los estipulado. Hasta ahí todo bien.
El cuadro combinado principal o 1 se halla en un formulario A y los otros tres combos se completan al entrar a un nuevo formulario B, accionando el botón "abrir formulario B", el cual se abre en modo diálogo.
Si tengo que completar nuevos registros pareciera funcionar todo perfecto, pero cuando por alguna equivocación tengo que cambiar una opción ya elegida en el cuadro combinado 1, al volver a ingresar al formulario B sólo el cuadro combinado 2 está en blanco o vacío; los cuadros combinados 3 y 4 mantienen las opciones elegidas anteriormente que ni siquiera pertenecen a las opciones esperadas por la nueva selección realizada en el cuadro 1 en formulario A.
De todos modos, si despliego la lista en combo 2 aparecen las categorías esperadas y al seleccionar una de ellas entonces sí se blanquean los combos 3 y 4 y las listas de los mismos son las sincronizadas.
La pregunta sería
¿Cómo lograr que los combos 3 y 4 también se blanqueen al cambiar la opción seleccionada en combo principal 1?
De modo de evitar confusión en otro usuario.
Intenté llevar el id del combo 1 como "default value" al formulario B -a través de un evento en el generador de código-, para ver si se "activaba" la sincronización de los combos 3 y 4, por lo que deberían vaciarse si hay opciones de lista no correspondientes a la nueva selección en el principal, pero en este caso lo que sucede es que el valor por default del combo 1 transportado al formulario B no se actualiza al modificar el combo 1 del formulario A.
Saludos gracias.
PD: añadido por sugerencia de comentario
esta sincronizado por medio de un default value del id principal del registro del formulario A, id_intervencion, el cual se lleva al formulario B en evento al cargar
F_CARGA_INTERVENCION_EOE es el formulario A que contiene el combo 1
F_MOTIVOS_CATEGORIAS_DATOS es el formulario B que se abre desde el A y tiene los combos asociados 2,3 y 4
Private Sub Form_Load()
Id_intervencion.DefaultValue = Forms! 
[F_CARGA_INTERVENCION_EOE]!Id_intervencion
End Sub

por otro lado en el origen de la fila del combo 2, en la consulta de hoja de propiedades, se asocia a la llave externa (id_combo1) de la tabla que trae los valores de dicho combo mediante el generador en la fila criterios: Formularios]![F_CARGA_INTERVENCION_EOE]![cdro_motivo_intervencion] >>> este es el combo 1
Del mismo modo esta hecho con los otros combos del combo 3 al 2 y del 4 al 3, más los eventos "despues de actualizar" de combo 2 y 3
Private Sub cdro_2_AfterUpdate()
Me.cdro_3 = vbNullString
Me.cdro_3.Requery
Me.cdro_4 = vbNullString
Me.cdro_4.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cdro_3_AfterUpdate()
Me.cdro_4 = vbNullString
Me.cdro_4.Requery
End Sub


Lo que no explicas es cómo haces para que el valor de los combos 2, 3 y 4 dependan de los valores seleccionados en los combos anteriores. Sospecho que la respuesta depende de ello.

gracias edité tu sugerencia a mi pregunta
